# How can i match inner expression on nested expression with regular expressions?

Tags: c#, regex

I got this code on c#

This works:

```
string code = "dqwdSTART12sdaSTART12312ENDsdfSTARTasdsaENDasdaENDqwe";
string pattern = "START[^(START)(END)]*END";
```

But not this:

```
string code = "dqwdstart12sdastart12312endsdfstartasdsaendasdaendqwe";
string pattern = "start[^(start)(end)]*end";
```

How can i do the match ?

( preferably c # )

Comment: Are you sure you have associated the right code string with the right pattern string? Both regexes match their corresponding code for me.

Answer (score 2):

this pattern `[^(start)(end)]` does not mean what you think, it does not mean non of the words but non of the characters enclosed between `[` and `]`
the only reason why it worked is because you had numbers between `start` and `end`, if you add a letter like `s` it won't work.

use this pattern instead

```
START((?:(?!START|END).)*)END
```

with `gi` options
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/130)

```
START           # "START"
(               # Capturing Group (1)
  (?:           # Non Capturing Group
    (?!         # Negative Look-Ahead
      START     # "START"
      |         # OR
      END       # "END"
    )           # End of Negative Look-Ahead
    .           # Any character except line break
  )             # End of Non Capturing Group
  *             # (zero or more)(greedy)
)               # End of Capturing Group (1)
END             # "END"
```

Comment: This works great !, thanks, i need to study a little more regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

```
(?<=start)(?:(?!start|end).)*(?=end)
```

You can try this as well if you dont want to capture `start` and `end` and just the content between.See demo,

http://regex101.com/r/yP3iB0/23